# MongoDb 3.0.1 java driver GridFs error

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I'm upgrading one app to Mongo java driver 3.0.1. Everything works well except GridFs file saving. It works well with old java driver (2.12.4). Now I'm using mongodb-driver-core y mongodb-driver 3.0.1.

My code:

```
DB mongoDbFiles;
GridFS attachFile;
GridFSInputFile gfsFile;
mongoDbFiles = mongo.getDB("UserWebFiles");
attachFile = new GridFS(mongoDbFiles, "UserFiles");
    ..........
gfsFile = attachFile.createFile(new File("C:/dxl/" + (String) vFileNames.get(k)));
gfsFile.setFilename((String) vFileNames.get(k));
gfsFile.save();
```

In the save gives the error:
 *com.mongodb.MongoException: couldn't save chunks*

*Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed*

Has something changed with GridFs in the new drivers?

As I said it works well with driver 2.12.4. Java version 8 (jdk 1.8.0_25 - 32 bits)

Thanks in advance,

Augusto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in the mongo-driver-3.0.1.jar file. I corrected one of the GrisFS.createFile functions. I compiled again the jar file and now it works well.

If anyone has that problem I can send the jar file. I will try to send the correction to Mongo.

Comment: MongoDB Developer Team answered: This has been fixed in 3.0.x and on master and will be released in 3.0.2 and later in 3.1.

Comment: @Augusto Can i know what the changes you have done i am also facing the `Mongo Exception: Cannot save chunks` when i try to save file in MongoDB .I ma using mongo-java-driver 3.0.1

Comment: @Vicky - the ticket it was fixed in is here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1813

Comment: ok @Ross so i have to edit the jar file to `public GridFSInputFile createFile(final File file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            return createFile(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName(), true);
        } finally {
           fileInputStream.close();
        }
    }` and recompile it right ?

Comment: Probably easier to use the underlying method instead:

`createFile(final InputStream in, final String filename, final boolean closeStreamOnPersist)`  So update your code calling `createFile(file)` to:
`createFile(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName(), true)`